Is there an tool or application that will allow me to dowload all the videos from someone's YouTube channel?
I'd like to know if there a tool or application that can copy all the videos from another user's YouTube channel.
This would allow me to have a local copy of content I like in case the channel owner decides to remove the content which has happened in the past.
I've seen apps that allow me to download individual videos, or even playlists, but I couldn't find a way to download an entire channel that may have thousands of videos that may not be organized in playlists.
An ideal automated solution would not just download the channel content, but also re-upload it to my own channel.

Does this answer your question? Software to download YouTube videos to hard drive
